# Vector Geometry - Proving that a polygon is parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors

Question states:
"The sides $AD, AB, CB, CD$ of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ are divided by the points $E, F, G, H$ so that $AE: ED = AF: FB = CG: GB = CH: HD$. Prove that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram."

The question, although seemingly easy, is quite difficult for me. I expressed the sides of $EFGH$ as vectors with

$$HG = kGB - kHD$$
$$EF = kFB - kED$$
$$EH = \frac{1}{k}(HC - EA)$$
$$FG = \frac{1}{k}(GC - FA)$$

But I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: One of those equal ratios doesn't look like the others.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $AD : ED\,$? That's the only ratio that involves the length of a side of $ABCD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstrate that $EF$ is parallel to $DB$ and a fraction $k$ of it.

Then demonstrate that $HG$ is also parallel to $DB$ and is the same fraction of it.

So oposite sides of $EFGH$ are parallel - enough to prove that it is a parallelogram.

Comment: That's a good hint once the question is corrected to replace $\,AD : ED\,$ with $\,AE : ED\,$.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was clear enough from what you had said.

Comment: Thank you so much. And the error has been corrected.